# How can I send json data to an MS access database from PHP form?

Tags: php, json, database, forms, ms-access

I have been looking around for ages at MS Access and the database that my client is using. I've been trying to sort out how we can pass data into the MS Access database from submitted forms from the website.

The idea is basically this;

1. The user comes to the site and finds an application form
2. The user then puts data into the form and attaches a cv
3. They press send and it pushes the form data through the main site database.
4. This is where MS Access comes into play, the form should then generate json(which is the easy part) and then send that to the MS Access database that the client has created.

What is the best way that this can be approached?

Comment: You can use PDO to acess a MSAccess database `$db = new PDO("odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ=$dbName; Uid=; Pwd=;");`

Comment: Okay and then from this will it allow me to post to the database?

Comment: Is this also useful if I am building this and putting it onto a completely different server such as linux?

Comment: forget about json, read more about PDO :)

Comment: Some things to be aware: Access ODBC is local only. That means that your web server must be able to see the MS Access database as a local or network shared file. Also, you don't need JSON to perform database actions like form submission. You only need JSON if you want to read/write from the database without submitting a form.

Comment: So your saying to be able to do this I would need to be on a Windows pc to be built? Or could we run a script that pulls in the data from url on the site into the database on the MS Access db?